# Writing a Matrix to a Python file

Tags: python, file, format

I am new to python, I have a little problem, let's suppose I have the following 
Array: `L = [[ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 ] ,[ 2,5,8,9,6,4,7,3,42,7 ]]`, and I would like to write it to a text file under the format:

```
1  <\t>  2
2  <\t>  5
3  <\t>  8
4  <\t>  9
5  <\t>  6
6  <\t>  4
7  <\t>  7
8  <\t>  3
9  <\t>  42
10  <\t>  7
```

anyone has a quick solution ? 
I have tried :

```
L=[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],[2,5,8,9,6,4,7,3,42,7]]

thefile=open("testo.txt","w")

thefile.write("%s \t %s \n"  %L[1][:] %L[2][:])
```

and I get this error :

```
thefile.write("%s \t %s \n"  %L[1][:] %L[2][:])
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You almost got the idea, but you have wrong syntax for string interpolation `%`, and using `[:]` will print the whole inner list as a string, you need to use iteration. Try:

```
with open('testo.txt', 'w') as f:
    for i in range(len(L[1])):
        f.write("%s \t %s \n" % (L[0][i], L[1][i]))
```

or a more pythonic way:

```
with open('testo.txt', 'w') as f:
    for list_item_1, list_item_2 in zip(*L):
        f.write("%s \t %s \n" % (list_item_1, list_item_2))
```

Comment: I get this error : f.write("%s \t %s \n" % L[0][i], L[1][i])
                        TypeError: not enough arguments for format string                          and with f.writeline it says the attribute doesnt exist

Comment: Yes, sorry I prefer `.format()`. It should be a tuple, see edit.